# How to set up my Ubuntu nodeJS server, and upload my angularJS WebSites

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, yeoman

Does somebody know how to set up propertly websites based on angular (auto generated with yeoman) on ubuntu server?
Here is the thing, I have a project developed in angular, I generated it with yeoman (the basic example, on yeoman codelab). I can run it and see it working on my computer with "grunt serve", but I have no idea how to upload it to my server for access it from the internet.

On my ubuntu, I have installed apache2, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, and Node (i guess I do not need apache2 for all this, but I have it anyway).

I connect with putty and the command node works fine, npm works fine too.

I am searching info, but I only found how to run a service on the node (example:node test.js) but this is not the case.
But what I want to do is to upload a website (angular) for access it from the internet...
I uploaded the "app" folder (that has the index.html, styles, controllers, views, etc) of my angular website (generated with yeoman), i uploaded it on my www directory in ubuntu, but when I access angular, or styles doesn´t work.

So, the question is: Does NODE have a "www" directory (like in apache2) where I have to upload my websites (angular websites) for access it from the internet? or I have to run it with some kind of "grunt" or "node" command?
Because i can´t run it with "node index.html", and if i access it from the internet it doesn´t work either, so... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Angular runs on the client side.  Node acts as the server side, your JS there would likely / best be built in [sails](http://sailsjs.org/).  What you are talking about is a MEAN stack - so see this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

Answer (score 0):

If you have a runnable app on local then follow these steps:

1. Set it up on [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) and host on [github](http://github.com), bitbucket or any other git hosting and connect your server via [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and choose/make whatever directory. (Doesnt matter which direcory, I personally prefer `/var/www` )
2. Pull that repo in that directory.
3. Run the app using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or some process management tool like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

PS: grunt is more of a developer tool than production tool. so start your app directly using `node wahtever_your_server_file_is.js` in forever

Also make sure whatever port you are using to run the app is open on your server.